# How to add stroke around SVG group's external borders

Tags: css, svg, stroke

I have two rectangles next to each other in a group.

```
<g
   id="rectangles"
   transform="translate(-36.736202,-113.84452)">
   <rect
      id="left"
      style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;"
      width="37.5639"
      height="37.5639"
      x="36.986202"
      y="114.09452" />   
   <rect
      id="right"
      style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;"
      width="37.5639"
      height="37.5639"
      x="74.550102"
      y="114.09452" />
</g>
```

Would it be possible to give the group a stroke that goes around the whole group [like here: red border around the rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRYHM.png)?

I've found some approaches with **feMorphology** which sort of work but I'm wondering if there's a more clean and straightforward solution to this.

Comment: if you don't want to use svg filters you still can to <use> the 2 rects behind (before) the actual rects and give them a wide red stroke.

Comment: The straightforward solution is to draw a third rectangle with the red stroke.